# Chef shell_out premature call

Tags: iis, chef-infra

My recipe uses the IIS cookbook to delete then add and start an IIS website with `http` binding then adding the `https` bindings using the `shell_out` command as follows:

```
iis_site iis_site_name do
    action :delete
end


   ... other things ...

iis_site iis_site_name do
    protocol :http
    port 80
    path site_dir
    application_pool iis_site_name
    host_header site_header
    action [:add,:start]
end

if https
    https_binding(iis_site_name, site_header)
end


def https_binding(site_name, site_header)
  cmd = "#{appcmd} set site /site.name:\"#{site_name}\" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:#{site_header}']"
  Chef::Log.info("Running HTTPS config command")
  Chef::Log.debug(cmd)
  shell_out!(cmd, {:returns => [0,42]})
  Chef::Log.info("HTTPS config command run")
end
```

Looking at the debug log, it shows that the `https_binding` log debug/info calls are called prior to the IIS site being deleted:

```
[2013-08-30T16:22:01+00:00] INFO: Running HTTPS config command
[2013-08-30T16:22:01+00:00] DEBUG: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set site /site.name:"mysite" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:mysite.com']
ERROR ( message:New binding object missing required attributes. Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'binding'
with combined key attributes 'protocol, bindingInformation' respectively set to 'https, *:443:mysite.com'
. )
[2013-08-30T16:22:01+00:00] INFO: HTTPS config command run
 (up to date)
Recipe: <Dynamically Defined Resource>
* iis_site[mysite action delete[2013-08-30T16:22:01+00:00] INFO: Processing iis_site[mysite] action delete (c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/mycookbook/providers/website.rb line 47)
```

Why are these commands being run so late as opposed to when they're called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my code to the following seems work, but I don't like this method. Is there a better way?

```
deleteSite = iis_site iis_site_name do
end

deleteSite.run_action(:delete)


   ... other things ...

createSite = iis_site iis_site_name do
    protocol :http
    port 80
    path site_dir
    application_pool iis_site_name
    host_header site_header
end

createSite.run_action(:add)
createSite.run_action(:start)

if https
    https_binding(iis_site_name, site_header)
end


def https_binding(site_name, site_header)
  cmd = "#{appcmd} set site /site.name:\"#{site_name}\" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:#{site_header}']"
  Chef::Log.info("Running HTTPS config command")
  Chef::Log.debug(cmd)
  shell_out!(cmd, {:returns => [0,42]})
  Chef::Log.info("HTTPS config command run")
end
```